# when creating APIs in publisher page for 4.1.0 version wso2 it is not getting reflected

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

when creating APIs in publisher page for wso2 AM 4.1.0 version it is not getting reflected in wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api$ ,
like previously for WSO2 version 3.2.0 it was getting reflected .

any suggestion like what we need to change in the deployment.toml file or any file?

Answer (score 0):

API artifacts are persisted in memory and in the database from APIM 4.0.0 onwards. If you want the API artifacts in the file system similar to older versions of APIM you can add the following config in the `deployment.toml`. It is not recommended to follow this approach as the in-memory deployment is the default behaviour.

```
[synapse_properties]
'synapse.artifacts.file.storage.enabled' = true
```

Alternatively, you can use the Gateway API [1] also to view the API artifact without persisting it in the file system

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/reference/product-apis/gateway-apis/gateway-v2/gateway-v2/

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons:

1. Check `deployment.toml`, particularly check for the following properties are set properly:

   ```
   [apim.devportal]
   url = "https://localhost:9443/devportal"
   [apim.publisher]
   url = "https://localhost:9443/publisher"
   [apim.admin]
   url = "https://localhost:9443/admin"
   ```
2. Check `WSO2 API Manager server` to see whether there are errors or warnings related to API deployment

Comment: we have checked with your suggestions. When coming to the UI page we are getting a particular API error 404 NOT FOUND. even if it is published on the WSO2 APIM page. like for the previous version when we was creating it was getting reflected in the wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api$ mentioned path. 
So, I'm not sure, whether this error is related to that only and I have one more doubt, whether it is mandatory to reflect on APIs path.

Comment: You need to deploy it to be available in synapse-configs directory